# WPF Data Binding - Displaying the list of system fonts

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Using XAML, I am trying to get a list box to display the list of system fonts.

I am not sure exactly what to type in the Bindings string.

Here's my attempt:

```
<Window x:Class="ListDataBinding.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media;assembly=PresentationCore" 
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource m:Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}"></ListBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I get an error: Cannot find resource named '{m:Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}'

I'm wondering what I should be typing. I haven't managed to find a helpful MSDN page on this - if somebody could point me to a link I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="ListDataBinding.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media;assembly=PresentationCore" 
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
   <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="fontFamiliesKey" ObjectType="{x:Type m:Fonts}" MethodName="get_SystemFontFamilies"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource fontFamiliesKey}}"></ListBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Try this

Comment: How did you know about the get_SystemFontFamilies method?

Comment: @Frinavale, it is the property SystemFontFamilies, properties are compiled to get_PropertyName methods into an assembly

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your`Binding` source is set to **{StaticResource ...}**. It should be **{x:Static ...}** instead because `SystemFontFamilies` is a simple plain-old static CLR property on the `System.Windows.Media.Fonts` object, not any kind of resource. In fact you don't even need a `Binding`. This is all you need:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{x:Static m:Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}" />
```

---

You really should stop reading here, however you *can* be a little sneakier if you need maximum performance. With the above method--which you should definitely use--you're handing a `ICollection<FontFamily>` to **WPF** which is actually a `ReadOnlyCollection<FontFamily>` instance. That, in turn, is wrapping a simple array `FontFamily[]` containing the items you want.

Because of the extra wrapping layer, **WPF** [internally won't detect](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/ViewManager.cs,563) the optimal `CollectionView` when populating your UI control and will have to fall back to its slower iterative techniques. In this case, however, the wrapper inadvertently exposes the raw array through via its prehistoric `SyncRoot` support, so you can in fact access the `FontFamily[]` directly through that property if you wish.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static m:Fonts.SystemFontFamilies},
                               Path=(sc:ICollection.SyncRoot)}" />
```

Couple things about this. Note that we're back to using a `Binding` since the **{x:Static}** markup extension (`StaticExtension`) won't follow a property path beyond its one static property. Also note the cast to `ICollection` which is required here (i.e. WPF's way of frowning upon this in general). To support the cast, you'll need to add the `System.Collections` namespace to the top of your XAML file as shown below. And finally with this trick, you'll also lose the ability to see the fonts list in the Visual Studio XAML designer, but everything works just fine when actually running.

```
...
xmlns:sc="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

ItemsSource="{x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}"
its that simple :)