# Binding to a list of FontWeight and FontStyle values

Tags: wpf

I am trying to bind to the list of defined `FontWeights` and `FontStyles` in WPF.
I was hoping to use the same technique used in this thread about [Displaying the list of system fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170384/wpf-data-binding-displaying-the-list-of-system-fonts); however, I cannot documentation on the get_systemFontFaimlies method for `Fonts` structure and likewise I cannot find documentation for the `FontWeights` and `FontStyles` either.

Thank you for your help.

**Edit:**

While the response that @ethicallogics provided was helpful, and it is probably more flexible than my solution, I just simply declared arrays in my XAML and chose which `FontWeight` and `FontStyle` options I wanted to provide to the end user.

I also found documentation that I couldn't find yesterday for the `SystemFonts.get_systemFontFaimlies` method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fonts.systemfontfamilies%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It is a shame but it appears that the `FontWeights` and `FontStyles` structures do not have anything like the get method that the `SystemFonts` structure has which is why I had to explicitly define arrays with the items that I wanted to provide to the end user.

Here is my XAML for the arrays I defined:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:media="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media;assembly=PresentationCore"
     xmlns:win="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationCore"
     xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"> 

     <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="FontFamilyOptions" ObjectType="{x:Type media:Fonts}" MethodName="get_SystemFontFamilies"/>
      <x:Array x:Key="FontWeightOptions" Type="win:FontWeight">
          <win:FontWeight>Normal</win:FontWeight>
          <win:FontWeight>Bold</win:FontWeight>
          <win:FontWeight>ExtraBold</win:FontWeight>
      </x:Array>
      <x:Array x:Key="FontStyleOptions" Type="win:FontStyle">
          <win:FontStyle>Normal</win:FontStyle>
          <win:FontStyle>Italic</win:FontStyle>
          <win:FontStyle>Oblique</win:FontStyle>
      </x:Array>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just declared arrays as resources (with the options that I wanted to provide to the end user) in my XAML like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:media="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media;assembly=PresentationCore"
     xmlns:win="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationCore"
     xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"> 

     <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="FontFamilyOptions" ObjectType="{x:Type media:Fonts}" MethodName="get_SystemFontFamilies"/>
      <x:Array x:Key="FontWeightOptions" Type="win:FontWeight">
          <win:FontWeight>Normal</win:FontWeight>
          <win:FontWeight>Bold</win:FontWeight>
          <win:FontWeight>ExtraBold</win:FontWeight>
      </x:Array>
      <x:Array x:Key="FontStyleOptions" Type="win:FontStyle">
          <win:FontStyle>Normal</win:FontStyle>
          <win:FontStyle>Italic</win:FontStyle>
          <win:FontStyle>Oblique</win:FontStyle>
      </x:Array>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And I used these as the item sources for my combo boxes like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource FontFamilyOptions}}" />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource FontWeightOptions}}" />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource FontStyleOptions}}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a FontWrapper class like

```
public class FontsWrapper
{
    static ICollection<FontWeight> fontWeights;
    static ICollection<FontStyle> fontStyles;
    static ICollection<FontFamily> fontFamilies;

    public static ICollection<FontStyle> GetFontStyles()
    {
        return fontStyles ?? (fontStyles = new List<FontStyle>() { System.Windows.FontStyles.Italic, System.Windows.FontStyles.Normal, System.Windows.FontStyles.Oblique });//TODO:Get by reflection
    }

    public static ICollection<FontFamily> GetFontFamilies()
    {
        return fontFamilies ?? (fontFamilies = Fonts.SystemFontFamilies);
    }

    public static ICollection<FontWeight> GetFontWeights()
    {
        if (fontWeights == null)
            fontWeights = new List<FontWeight>();
        else
            return fontWeights;

        var type = typeof(FontWeights);
        foreach (var p in type.GetProperties().Where(s => s.PropertyType == typeof(FontWeight)))
        {
            fontWeights.Add((FontWeight)p.GetValue(null, null));
        }
        return fontWeights;
    }

    public static ICollection<FontWeight> FontWeights
    {
        get { return fontWeights ?? (fontWeights = GetFontWeights()); }
    }
    public static ICollection<FontStyle> FontStyles
    {
        get { return fontStyles ?? (fontStyles = GetFontStyles()); }
    }

    public static ICollection<FontFamily> FontFamilies
    {
        get { return fontFamilies ?? (fontFamilies = GetFontFamilies()); }
    }
}
```

> xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="fontFamiliesKey" ObjectType="{x:Type local:FontsWrapper}" MethodName="GetFontFamilies"/>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="fontWeightsKey" ObjectType="{x:Type local:FontsWrapper}" MethodName="GetFontStyles"/>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="fontStylesKey" ObjectType="{x:Type local:FontsWrapper}" MethodName="GetFontWeights"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource fontFamiliesKey}}"></ComboBox>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource fontWeightsKey}}"></ComboBox>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource fontStylesKey}}"></ComboBox>
    <!-- or Bind the Lists of wrapper class Directly -->
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:FontsWrapper.FontFamilies}}"></ComboBox>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:FontsWrapper.FontStyles}}"></ComboBox>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:FontsWrapper.FontWeights}}"></ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

I hope this will help.